# Smarter webpack bundling with react and express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I've got a react app going, and it's run on an express server and is bundling with webpack. My issue is that everytime I restart the server, like when i am making changes to it, it takes forever to rebuild the frontend bundle, even though i don't make any changes to the frontend.

It would be nice to just reload the server portion and leave the current frontend bundle in tact when just making server/api changes that don't involve the front end bundle.

Here is the code that run's in a dev environment:

```
 const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)
  const middleware = webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    contentBase: 'src',
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      hash: false,
      timings: true,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false,
      modules: false
    }
  })

  app.use(middleware)
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'build/app.html')))
    res.end()
  })
```

Is there a smarter way to do this? is it possible to leave the current frontend bundle in memory and just reload the server? Or can I detect if the bundle needs to be updated and skip the process if it doesn't need to be updated?

Any tips, advice and suggestions are welcome! Let me know if you need any other info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Chokidar solution**

If using webpack-dev-tools, a great library for watching changes is [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

> Chokidar does still rely on the Node.js core fs module, but when using
> fs.watch and fs.watchFile for watching, it normalizes the events it
> receives, often checking for truth by getting file stats and/or dir
> contents.

Here is a small example of using chokidar to watch only the targetfolder. By targeting just a specific folder you could leave the frontend intact. I haven't tried this for your specific use case but at first sight it seems that this may suit your needs.

```nodejs
var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
if(!production) {
  var chokidar = require('chokidar')
  var watcher = chokidar.watch('./targetfolder')
  watcher.on('ready', function() {
    watcher.on('all', function() {
      console.log("Clearing /targetfolder/ module cache from server")
      Object.keys(require.cache).forEach(function(id) {
        if (/[\/\\]targetfolder[\/\\]/.test(id)) delete require.cache[id]
      })
    })
  })
}
```

There's a great example on Github, called [Ultimate Hot Reloading Example](https://github.com/glenjamin/ultimate-hot-reloading-example)

NB:  The webpack-dev-server doesn't write files to disk, it serves the result from memory trough an Express instance. But webpack --watch does write files to disk.

**Flag solution**

You can use webpack's --watch flag.

In your package.json, the script block that starts your server (or the one that runs webpack), add this `webpack --progress --colors --watch`.

See [Webpack documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#watch-mode), it says:

> We don’t want to manually recompile after every change…
>
> When using watch mode, webpack installs file watchers to all files, which were used in the compilation process. If any change is detected, it’ll run the compilation again. When caching is enabled, webpack keeps each module in memory and will reuse it if it isn’t changed.

Example in package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
}
```

Comment: webpack is run in the server.js file though, the `webpack-dev-middleware` module gives a `lazy` option which seems to mirror what your quote says, but i don't really think that solves the issue, as stopping the server would remove the build from memory wouldn't it?

Comment: @ShanRobertson, I have edited my response. If you are working on a public repo, please share the link so I can test it out... `lazy: true;` means no watching, but recompilation on every request `watchOptions` only works if lazy is set to false. The webpack-dev-server doesn't write files to disk, it serves the result from memory trough an Express instance. But webpack --watch does write files to disk so you may keep the build.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in a SpringBoot app, where i can rebuild my bundle rapidly, but then that wouldn't necessarily make the server look inside an actual folder and find it live in realtime. So really what you need to do is have a way to configure your server to always look in a local folder for the bundle.js file instead of pulling it from the WAR/JAR or wherever it normally pulls it from. It's not "webpack issue". It's an issue of how to make servers read directly from the bundle.js on the folder. I would give you the Spring way of doing it but that's not your architecture.